# Loss function vs regularizer

Tags: machine-learning, regularization, loss-functions, robust

Probably this is an easy thing. But I am struggling with the concept of regularization and loss function. Let's assume that we want a robust sparse solution of a linear regression problem. The data is noisy. Then consider two setups:

1. As the data is noisy, we may use Huber Loss and for sparse solution L1 regularizer.
2. In the second one, we may use ε-Insensitive Loss which will give us both a sparse and robust solution. As a regularizer, we may use L2.

My question is which setup should I use? It seems I can achieve sparsity using regularizer (L1) or loss function (ε-Insensitive Loss). Should I try to achieve my goal using regularizer or loss function?

Another thing is that in setup 2, if ε-Insensitive Loss gives me a robust sparse solution, then why do we need a regularizer there?